# Как сделать чтобы при наведении на блок не скроллило?

Tags: битрикс

мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если мышка была на блоке swiper, тогда параметр navigation был false, я вроде бы написал, но код не работает почему-то

```
if (document.querySelector('#fullpage')) {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 993) {
        let isNavigationEnabled = true;

        const fullPageInstance = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
            navigation: isNavigationEnabled,
            navigationPosition: 'left',
            scrollHorizontally: true,
            onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction, trigger) {
                var origin = this;
                const el = document.querySelector('.header__column-location');
                el.classList.remove("view");
                if (origin.index == 0 && direction =='down') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.add('scroll');
                } else if (origin.index == 2 && direction == 'down') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.remove('scroll');
                } else if (origin.index == 3 && direction == 'down') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.add('scroll');
                } else if (origin.index == 6 && direction == 'down') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.remove('scroll');
                } else if (origin.index == 7 && direction == 'up') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.add('scroll');
                } else if (origin.index == 4 && direction == 'up') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.remove('scroll');
                } else if (origin.index == 3 && direction == 'up') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.add('scroll');
                } else if (origin.index == 1 && direction == 'up') {
                    document.querySelector('#fp-nav.fp-left').classList.remove('scroll');
                };
            },
        });

        const elementOne = document.querySelector('.swiper');

        elementOne.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            isNavigationEnabled = false;
            fullPageInstance.setOptions({ navigation: isNavigationEnabled });
        });

        elementOne.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            isNavigationEnabled = true;
            fullPageInstance.setOptions({ navigation: isNavigationEnabled });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверяйте: Срабатывает ли событие наведения мыши. Срабатывает ли метод setOptions. Как этот метод обрабатывает полученные значения. В коде нет класса fullpage, поэтому сказать что то сложно

Comment: срабатывает наведение мыши, как мне проверить срабатывает ли метод setOptions,

Comment: `console.log()` добавьте и посмотрите